# Firebase flat database update method

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database is below. I’m having a hard time understanding how to access the properties, (ie. address) for a specific record so I can update it. I’ve been pushing the data as items are added. So should I be storing the id along with my data so I can use it?

[image: image of firebase data]

Answer (score 2):

```
 private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;

mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

//change your variable to something easy to read like info

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("info").child("address");
mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue("set_your_updated_value_here");
```

Comment: How to I specify which item I want to change the address property of?

Comment: Ok so “info” is loaded, by me, with the id I get when pushing it, or is info something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used that ended up working.

```
mMessagesDatabaseReference = firebaseRef.child(dbItemKey).child("status");
    mMessagesDatabaseReference.set( document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML)
```

Where dbItemKey = the unique key assigned to the parent, "status" being the child element I wanted to update. "userName" being the variable I pushed into the child element.

I also use .set() because I wasn't worried about overwriting the data in the specific child.

The actual implementation is not so good as I'm using this as a quick test of firebase and its usage.

The one thing I did learn was there is a small chance that the random Id firebase gives could be a duplicate as its a timestamp and random numbers put together.